# How to import a text file in a NodeJS app with TypeScript and ts-node in dev mode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, ts-node

I have a NodeJS/Express app that I'm developing using TypeScript, Nodemon and ts-node. In this app I have a `.txt` file containing some (long) text. I'm trying to read the content of the file and just log it to the console in *dev mode*.

```
import MyText from "./something.txt";

export const runIt = () => {
    console.log(MyText);
};
```

I'm importing the file directly (instead of using `fs`) because of a business requirement for keeping the number of deployed files to a minimum, which means that I have to bundle the code using Webpack and the text file is loaded with:

```
module.exports = {
    /*...*/
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.txt/,
                type: 'asset/source'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This works: running the `backend.js` bundle correctly "loads" the file and logs its content.

The problem comes in *dev mode*. When I start the dev server using `ts-node --files ./src/server.ts` I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` because it's trying to parse the content of the `.txt` file as a module (from what I can deduce...).

What additional configuration am I missing? Is there a solution for this scenario? Is there an alternative for reading text (from) files that works well even after bundling?

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-a-text-file-using-webpack-typescript-and-node-9qorz?file=/src/server.ts) that reproduces my problem.

Comment: exact same problem did u find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

During dev you can register a module loader

```js
// txt.js
/**
 * 
 * Allow import/require raw text file
 */
const fs = require('fs')
require.extensions[".txt"]= (m, fileName)=> {
  return m._compile(`module.exports=\`${fs.readFileSync(fileName)}\``, fileName);
}
```

launch it like this

```bash
node -r ts-node/register -r ./txt.js src/server.ts
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-2zunvu

Comment: I forked the codesandbox in the original answer here: https://codesandbox.io/s/get-a-text-file-using-webpack-typescript-and-node-forked-z2wdo1?file=/nodemon.json .  I can't get it to actually launch the `dev` script at startup but you can open a terminal and run `npm run dev`.  This launches your suggested command, but now fails with `Cannot find module './something.txt'` -- it's ignoring the wildcard module definition in `types/global/index.d.ts`

Comment: I noticed that , I assumed its a bug or not supported ;)

Comment: I assumed is the codesandbox environment but I was wrong, is ts-node complaining, you can set the --transpile-only flag to mute the error